# Elasticsearch - Has_Parent or Has_Child query returning empty results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm using Elasticsearch RC 2.0.0.

I got some parent-child relations In my Elasticsearch db. I want to retrieve all Children related to a parent object. I always receive an empty list of results. I followed the instructions of the elasticsearch documentation and I compared my code to several Books. I don't understand, why my query should return an empty result.

In this case I built an simplified example. I put two objects to elasticsearch and set object a as the parent of object b. Then I try to retrieve all objects, wich have a parent of type a.

This is my Input:

```
PUT test

PUT test/myobject/_mapping
    {
        "myobject":{
        "_parent" : {"type":"pobject"},
        "properties" : {
         "name" : {"type":"string"}   
        }

        }
    }

    PUT test/pobject/_mapping
    {
        "pobject" : {
            "properties": {
                "name": {"type":"string"}
            }

        }

    }

    PUT test/pobject/1
    {
        "name":"theParent"
    }

    PUT test/myobject/1?_parent=1&routing=_id
    {
        "name":"theChild"
    }

    POST test/myobject/_search?routing=_id
    {
         "query":{
            "has_parent":{
                 "type":"pobject",
            "query":{
                "match_all":{}
            }
            }
        }


    }
```

This will return

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is here: `PUT test/myobject/1?_parent=1&routing=_id`

*The parameter is `parent`, not `_parent`.*

```
POST test/myobject/1?parent=1
{
  "name": "theChild"
}
```

Also, you don't need to use `routing=_id`. See the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-parent-child.html).

The complete list of commands to test:

```
DELETE test
PUT test

PUT test/myobject/_mapping
{
  "myobject": {
    "_parent": {
      "type": "pobject"
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/pobject/_mapping
{
  "pobject": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/pobject/1
{
  "name": "theParent"
}

POST test/myobject/1?parent=1
{
  "name": "theChild"
}

POST test/myobject/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "parent_type": "pobject",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I still receive an empty resultlist. anyway when I call test/myobject/1 I see that there is a parent registered for this item.

Comment: Cause: I used the wrong name for the parents type-parameters ("type"  instead of "parent_type"), also I did a mistake when using the mapping parameter. thanks

Comment: I made the same mistake of indexing it using `routing` instead of `parent`